# Why does .loc work with integer index positions?

Tags: python, pandas, series

The pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html) of `.loc` clearly states:

> .loc is strictly label based, will raise KeyError when the items are
>   not found, allowed inputs are:
>
> A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (note that 5 is interpreted as a label
>   of the index. This use is not an integer position along the index)

Contrary to that, this surprisingly works **for pd.Series**, not for pd.DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,1,2])
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(a, index=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
s.loc["a"] # yields 1
s.loc[0] # should be strictly label-based, but it works and also yields 1
```

Do you know why?

Comment: On pandas version 0.13 I get an error: `'the label [0] is not in the [index]'`. What version are you running?

Comment: This could be a bug that has been fixed in `0.13`, as I am still using `0.12`. Despite that, the feature was introducted in `0.11`, so I am not sure whether this is the reason.

Comment: @Tobias this indeed was a bug fix that was not detected until the 0.13 release milestone.