# Why does .loc behave differently depending on whether values are printed or assigned?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I got confused about the following behavior. When I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), columns=list('ABCD'), index=list('bcdefg'))
```

which looks as follows:

```
          A         B         C         D
b -0.907325  0.211740  0.150066 -0.240011
c -0.307543  0.691359 -0.179995 -0.334836
d  1.280978  0.469956 -0.912541  0.487357
e  1.447153 -0.087224 -0.176256  1.319822
f  0.660994 -0.289151  0.956900 -1.063623
g -1.880520  1.099098 -0.759683 -0.657774
```

I receive the **expected** error

> TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexers [3] of type 'int'

when I try the following slice using `.loc`:

```
print df.loc[3:, ['C', 'D']]
```

It is expected as I pass an integer as an index and not one of the letters contained in the `index`.

However, if I now try

```
df.loc[3:, ['C', 'D']] = 10
```

it works fine and gives me the output:

```
          A         B          C          D
b -0.907325  0.211740   0.150066  -0.240011
c -0.307543  0.691359  -0.179995  -0.334836
d  1.280978  0.469956  -0.912541   0.487357
e  1.447153 -0.087224  10.000000  10.000000
f  0.660994 -0.289151  10.000000  10.000000
g -1.880520  1.099098  10.000000  10.000000
```

My question is why the same command fails when something is printed and why it works when a value is assigned. When I check the doc string for `.loc`, I would have expected that this would always result in the error mentioned above (see especially the bold part):

> Allowed inputs are:
>
> - A single label, e.g. `5` or `'a'`, (**note that `5` is   interpreted as a *label* of the index, and **never** as an   integer
>     position along the index**).
> - A list or array of labels, e.g. `['a', 'b', 'c']`.
> - A slice object with labels, e.g. `'a':'f'` (note that contrary   to usual python slices, **both** the start and the stop are
>     included!).
> - A boolean array.
> - A `callable` function with one argument (the calling Series, DataFrame   or Panel) and that returns valid output for indexing (one
>     of the above)
>
> `.loc` will raise a `KeyError` when the items are not found.

Any explanation for that; what am I missing here?

**EDIT**

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574882/why-does-loc-work-with-integer-index-positions?rq=1) similar behavior is considered a bug which was fixed in 0.13. I use 0.19.1.

**EDIT 2**
Building up on @EdChum's post, one can do the following:

```
df.loc[2] = 20
df.loc[3] = 30
df.loc[4] = 40
```

which yields

```
           A          B          C          D
b   0.083326  -1.047032   0.830499  -0.729662
c   0.942744  -0.535013   0.809251   1.132983
d  -0.074918   1.123331  -2.205294  -0.497468
e   0.213349   0.694366  -0.816550   0.496324
f   0.021347   0.917340  -0.595254  -0.392177
g  -1.149890   0.965645   0.172672  -0.043652
2  20.000000  20.000000  20.000000  20.000000
3  30.000000  30.000000  30.000000  30.000000
4  40.000000  40.000000  40.000000  40.000000
```

However, that is then still confusing to me because while

```
print df.loc['d':'f', ['C', 'D']]
```

works fine, the command

```
print df.loc[2:4, ['C', 'D']]
```

gives the index error mentioned above.

Additionally, when one now assigns values like this

```
df.loc[2:4, ['C', 'D']] = 100
```

the dataframe looks as follows:

```
           A          B           C           D
b   0.083326  -1.047032    0.830499   -0.729662
c   0.942744  -0.535013    0.809251    1.132983
d  -0.074918   1.123331  100.000000  100.000000
e   0.213349   0.694366  100.000000  100.000000
f   0.021347   0.917340   -0.595254   -0.392177
g  -1.149890   0.965645    0.172672   -0.043652
2  20.000000  20.000000   20.000000   20.000000
3  30.000000  30.000000   30.000000   30.000000
4  40.000000  40.000000   40.000000   40.000000
```

So the values are not added where one - or at least I - would expect them to be added (the position rather than the label is used).

Comment: According to https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy the first case calls "__getitem__" while the assignment case calls the "__setitem__" method. I'm assuming the second method is designed to handle slicing with integers

Comment: The key here is that ".loc is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array. .loc will raise KeyError when the items are not found"

So when you try indexing using the key 'e' instead of 3, it slices the data.
df.loc['e':, ['C', 'D']]

Comment: @Prateek: It is exactly the same method, I think. but one time it is `print df.loc[3:, ['C', 'D']]` the other time `df.loc[3:, ['C', 'D']] = 10`. So in both cases, `.loc` is used, there is no chained indexing (I think).

Comment: @VaishaliGarg: Yes, but I don't pass a Boolean array but and integer representing an index. That should always fail, as far as I understood the doc string. However, the assignment works, while the printing fails.

Comment: @Cleb From the same link it mentions that `dfmi.loc[:,('one','second')]`  passes a nested tuple of (slice(None),('one','second')) to a single call to `__getitem__` while `dfmi.loc[:,('one','second')] = value` becomes `dfmi.loc.__setitem__((slice(None), ('one', 'second')), value)`. The first case in your example with print is executed via the getitem method. This seems like a reasonable explantion too because glancing at the indexing.py class in the pandas codebase suggests that `__setitem__` has more conditions and methods to detect/expand indexes than `__getitem__`.

Comment: @Prateek: Thanks for your detailed comment. Do you think that is the desired behavior or shall I maybe open an issue for that? In the link I added to my question, it sounds more as this behavior is a bug.

Comment: Honestly I don't know. It feels like they treated it as 2 different use cases and handled them differently. But unless someone part of the Pandas team comments it's merely speculation.

Comment: I think this is kinda expected behaviour although a little surprising, for instance you're allowed to assign to a row label that doesn't exist: `df.loc[3] = 10` will work as this is expansion, whilst here you're passing an integer slice and this is converting it to an ordinal slice as the labels don't exist so this seems like undocumented or unclear semantics, the docs mainly talk about selection for indexing as opposed to assigning using a slice, also the question you link to is about selection without assignment so is different

Comment: Regarding the latest edit, it's not desirable to have mixed dtypes in the index and where the order is ambiguous. I'm still not sure this is really a bug rather than un-clarified semantics, without the slicing semantics then the `loc` will correctly lookup the label and assign with enlargement. When passing a slice there maybe caveats with respect to usage semantics, for instance if in your latest example it just worked as you expected then what should it do if the index is reverse sorted or unsorted? I think this is something worth suggesting as an improvement on github

Comment: @EdChum: Thanks a lot for your comment. I will wait for one or two more days and then post it on github as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug rather undocumented semantics, for instance setting with enlargement is allowed for the simple case where the row label doesn't exist:

```
In [22]:
df.loc[3] = 10
df

Out[22]:
           A          B          C          D
b  -0.907325   0.211740   0.150066  -0.240011
c  -0.307543   0.691359  -0.179995  -0.334836
d   1.280978   0.469956  -0.912541   0.487357
e   1.447153  -0.087224  -0.176256   1.319822
f   0.660994  -0.289151   0.956900  -1.063623
g  -1.880520   1.099098  -0.759683  -0.657774
3  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000
```

and if we pass a slice the labels aren't found in the slice but as it's an integer slice it gets converted to an ordinal slice:

```
In [24]:
df.loc[3:5] = 9
df

Out[24]:
           A          B          C          D
b  -0.907325   0.211740   0.150066  -0.240011
c  -0.307543   0.691359  -0.179995  -0.334836
d   1.280978   0.469956  -0.912541   0.487357
e   9.000000   9.000000   9.000000   9.000000
f   9.000000   9.000000   9.000000   9.000000
g  -1.880520   1.099098  -0.759683  -0.657774
3  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000
```

the post you linked and the bug was referring to selection without assignment where a non-existent label is being passed which should raise a `KeyError`, which is different here

If we look at [`__setitem__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L2374):

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)

        # see if we can slice the rows
        indexer = convert_to_index_sliceable(self, key))
```

Here it will try to convert the slice calling [`convert_to_index_sliceable`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1884):

```
def convert_to_index_sliceable(obj, key):
    """if we are index sliceable, then return my slicer, otherwise return None
    """
    idx = obj.index
    if isinstance(key, slice):
        return idx._convert_slice_indexer(key, kind='getitem')
```

If we look at the docstrings for this:

> Signature: df.index._convert_slice_indexer(key, kind=None) Docstring:
>   convert a slice indexer. disallow floats in the start/stop/step
>
> Parameters
>   ---------- key : label of the slice bound kind : {'ix', 'loc', 'getitem', 'iloc'} or None

and then run this:

```
In [29]:
df.index._convert_slice_indexer(slice(3,5),'loc')

Out[29]:
slice(3, 5, None)
```

this is then used to slice the index:

```
In [28]:
df.index[df.index._convert_slice_indexer(slice(3,5),'loc')]

Out[28]:
Index(['e', 'f'], dtype='object')
```

So we see that even though you passed what appeared to be non-existent labels, the integer slice object was converted into an ordinal slice that was compatible with the df according to different rules

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. However, that leads to even more confusion (see my Edit 2).